# Full screen standalone game in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, fullscreen

How to make my Unity3d standalone game run on full screen mode be default?

I tried to change the player settings but without any luck. I don't wanna see any toolbar above my game, or any close or resize buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in code, e.g.

```
public class FullscreenByDefault : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = true;
    }
}
```

or in any existing `MonoBehaviour`

Comment: Thanks! I struggled with this for so long.

Answer (score 4):

The following Player Settings will open the game with fullscreen exclusive mode, without any prompts:

[image: Fullscreen Player Settings]

Tested with Unity 5.6.0f3

Comment: Unfortunately this is something you can set or change only if your game is not distributed. Once the game is launched these settings are written to registry and the only way to override them is via script. After the first launch this window is useless if resolution dialog is disabled. This can make you pull hairs if you modify these during development as well. So script way is safer and saner.